# Django and Salesforce Web to Lead

Tags: django, django-forms, salesforce

We have website developers redesigning the whole site in Django, and these are questions from our website developers I don't have any real knowledge of how to answer, so I thought someone here might be able to help.

We ran into a few problems with the web to lead and having it map to Salesforce which I HOPE we resolved.

Here's the code snippet:

```html
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
<!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
<!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="SFDCidhere">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
<!--  value="emailaddresshere">                                     -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="company">Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>

Subject:<textarea  id="00N1600000EgFuw" name="00N1600000EgFuw" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>

Contact me:<input  id="00N1600000EvgRY" name="00N1600000EvgRY" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>

newsletter:<input  id="00N1600000EvgRd" name="00N1600000EvgRd" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

That's what the web-to-lead from SFDC generates, and seems to work now.

However they have 2 questions I am not certain about and would love assistance with:

1) The specs for the new site require that the return page be the one the form was sent from (I.e., no redirection; we’re intending to do the equivalent of a “thanks” page as a pop-up onClick() — how is that accomplished through the API? I’d EXPECT that sending an empty retURL value should do it, but we just get back a blank page with a salesforce.com URL;

2) is it possible to customize the “name” parameter for the two checkbox fields (if not then we have to hack the entire form in the Django template without making it possible for Django to render the form natively since you can’t have a model form field name start with a digit…). This isn’t THAT problematic, but I’d like to know for future reference.

If anyone has any insight, I'd love to hear it and pass it along to them!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your solution.

The common way that you could using the Partner WSDL or Enterprise WSDL to insert,update,upsert ,delete your data

Parnter WSDL:
  not custom from your salesforce org, but it could be common way to get your data.

In python your could use this package
 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyforce/1.4

And reference by this
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner.htm

Enterprise WSDL will show your salesforce org status (including field and object) . But one your objects or fields are changing that it might be error.

So i suggest using api to control the redirect function and the action.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll pass that along to them and see what they say.

Comment: if you think i have solve your problem plz give me an answer or vote , thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows in an example

```
    from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
    from django.conf import settings

    def set_field_html_name(cls, new_name):
        """
        This creates wrapper around the normal widget rendering,
        allowing for a custom field name (new_name).
        """
        old_render = cls.widget.render

        def _widget_render_wrapper(name, value, attrs=None):
            return old_render(new_name, value, attrs)

        cls.widget.render = _widget_render_wrapper


    class WebToLeadForm(forms.Form):
        # <keep all fields here>
        # example field below
        referred_by = forms.CharField(label="Referred By", required=False)
        # The reCAPTCHA in this form uses keys from settings.
        captcha = ReCaptchaField()

        set_field_html_name(referred_by, settings.SF_REFERRED_BY)
```

settings.py 
SF_REFERRED_BY = '00xxxxxxxxxxxx'